# Eloquent: has() condition against database value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a simple relationship between Bottles and InventoryItems:

##### InventoryItem.php:

```php
public function bottles(): HasMany
{
   return $this->hasMany(InventoryItemBottle::class);
}
```

I'm trying to query for InventoryItem's that have a bottles count of greater then a user entered threshold.

The user's input is saved in a JSONB. Part of the query looks like this and I've commented the problem line:

```php
->when(
    $filters['filter'] === 'show_above_max_threshold',
    fn (Builder $query): Builder => $query->where(function (Builder $query): Builder {
        return $query->whereColumn('info->quantity', '>', 'info->high_level_warning');
    })
    ->orWhere(function (Builder $query): Builder {
        return $query->has('bottles', '>', 'info->high_level_warning'); // stuck here
    })
)
```

The `has()` method should help here, but how do I get the `high_level_warning` from the database to pass to it? Or is there another method I could use?

Comment: what is `high_level_warning` ?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur, it is a int value entered by the user and stored in the database

Comment: you have to call the join relationship to bottles, in this case try adding bottles relationship at the end , like so `return $query->has('bottles', '>', 'info->high_level_warning')->with('bottles');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `has` function.
See if this helps you.

```
$threshold = 2;
$items = InventoryItem::has('bottles', '>=', $threshold)->get();
```

Comment: Yes, but the `$theshold` is coming from the database.